# sharetribe homepage error after login in sharetribe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharetribe

After login with http://52.27.73.120:3000/ in sharetribe. I getting the errors. It is also mentioned that this is fresh installation of sharetribe. But i am getting errors after login in the system. If someone help me to figure out the issue. I will be greatful. Thanks in advance.

```
No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - app/assets/webpack/server-bundle.js
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried to precompile your assets?

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: It works for me after running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My npm installation isn't working properly. After the installation of node and npm in my system and also running the `npm install` it install all the react components required by my sharetribe application. It is now properly working.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install the npm modules or your npm modules installation is failed.

Please try to install npm modules

```
npm install
```

If you have any issues, this [link](https://www.sharetribe.com/community/t/help-webpack-and-react/151) will help you.